# What does 'secret_key' stand for in webapp2 framework?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, session, cookies

I am just playing around with google app engine, webapp2, and python; I am just building a small toy app for fun. *A small side note, using ndb for google app engine datastore.*

With building a small webapp, comes sessions.

I was reading the webapp2 documentation on sessions, as well as the most popular threads on this website on how to setup sessions. What I don't get about this process is this small piece of code in the config.

```
config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
}
```

I am pretty new to web development. However, building other smaller apps with this same framework, I done the following to build somewhat secured hashed cookies.

```
 user_key = user_key.id()
 user_cookie = self.request.cookies.get('user_cookie', None)
```

and

```
self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie','user=%s|%s' % (user_cookie, hash_string(user_cookie)))
self.write('Thank you for sigining up! And, welcome %s' % user.name)
```

Is that what the first bit of code above for the config is trying to accomplish?
In other words what is this secret key for?

Also, lets say I want to set the 'sessions' cookie to the user id. 
Would the code below be the correct way to do this?

```
self.session[name] = user_key.id()
session_info = self.session.get(name)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `secret_key` is used by the *server* to digitally sign the cookie data that you are reading when you are calling `self.request.cookies.get('user_cookie', None)`.

The cookies are continually passed from client to server along with the digital signature. When the client presents the cookie values to the server with each request it does so with the digital signature given by the server. Each time the server signs the current cookie values, if the signature passed in by the client does not match the current server values the server knows the parameters of the cookie have been tampered with. This guards against a malicious client trying to impersonate another user or otherwise perform an unauthorised action.

This scheme only works if the key is only known to the server, otherwise any client could also sign cookies that the server would accept. Hence `secret_key`.

The default signature algorithm in webapp2 is [HMAC-SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

> Also, quickly, when I look at the cookie set by instantiating sessions, it is an extremely long string

This is [the code](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/webapp2_extras/securecookie.html#SecureCookieSerializer.deserialize) that the server uses to authenticate a cookie if you are curious. You'll notice that the cookie is base64 encoded json document.

> Now I suppose that the value of secret_key can then be any string that you'd like it to be, correct?

As they spell out from RFC 2104 on this [security thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/95977) any string of 20 or more randomly chosen bytes should do for HMAC-SHA1.

> Also, lets say I want to set the 'sessions' cookie to the user id

I think this is probably the [example](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.SessionStore) you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect, the conceptual explanation that I was looking for. Now I suppose that the value of  `secret_key` can then be any string that you'd like it to be, correct? Also, quickly, when I look at the cookie set by instantiating sessions, it is an extremely long string. Any idea where all of these characters come from? Probably something to do with the `secret sessions` as well. Thanks again.